# Difference between the Ruby Matrix Eigenvalue Decomposition and Numpy

Tags: ruby, numpy, matrix, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I'm trying to use the Ruby (2.5.1) Matrix Class for the calculation of a Singular Value Decomposition. While building the code I found a difference between the Python Numpy SVD results and the corresponding Ruby Matrix approach. The basis approach is as follows:

- A: Matrix to be processed
- X: A*AT Matrix A multiplied with Matrix A transposed
- Y: AT*A Matrix A transposed multiplied with Matrix A

with this:

- U is composed of the columns of the Eigenvectors of X
- S is the diagonal matrix of the square-root Eigenvalues ordered by the size
- V is composed of the row Eigenvectors of Y

The following matrix product produces matrix A again:

- A = U*S*VT

Comparing the Ruby Matrix Class and Numpy it comes up with the same results up to n of U < 4. But as soon as n > 4 within U the results of columns 4 and up start to differ from the Numpy results. I'm now wondering if I'm doing something wrong here or if there is a problem with the Matrix class in general.

For Numpy I used the following code

```
# Calculate and reconstruct SVD
from numpy import array
from numpy import diag
from numpy import dot
from numpy import zeros
from scipy.linalg import svd
# define a matrix
A = array([[1,1,1], [0,1,1], [1,0,0], [0,1,0], [1,0,0]])

print(A)
# Singular-value decomposition
U, s, VT = svd(A)
print('Matrix U')
print(U)
print('Eigenvektor')
print(s)
print('Matrix VT')
print(VT)
# create m x n Sigma matrix
Sigma = zeros((A.shape[0], A.shape[1]))
# populate Sigma with n x n diagonal matrix
Sigma[:A.shape[1], :A.shape[1]] = diag(s)
# reconstruct matrix
B = U.dot(Sigma.dot(VT))
print(B)
```

For the Ruby calculation I used the following code:

```
require 'matrix'
a = Matrix[ [1,1,1], [0,1,1], [1,0,0], [0,1,0], [1,0,0]]

x = a * a.transpose
y = a.transpose * a

u = Matrix::EigenvalueDecomposition.new(x)
u_ev = u.eigenvector_matrix().to_a

v = Matrix::EigenvalueDecomposition.new(y)
v_ev = v.eigenvector_matrix().transpose.to_a

u_ev.map! {|row| row.reverse}
v_ev.reverse!

puts 'Matrix U'
u = Matrix[*u_ev]
puts u.to_a.map(&:inspect)
puts 'Matrix V'
vt = Matrix[*v_ev]
puts vt.to_a.map(&:inspect)
puts 'Eigenvalues S'
p sqrt_diagonal_values = v.eigenvalues().map {|value| Math.sqrt(value)}.reverse
```

The results of the Numpy code are (example of the first row of U)

Matrix U

-7.40847968e-01 -1.08616810e-01  1.98359970e-01  5.12144302e-01 -3.71090574e-01

...

Eigenvector s

2.32131207 1.47894683 0.65132674

Matrix VT

-0.50752384 -0.6681011 -0.54411439

-0.85772795 0.45183049 0.24525898

-0.08198967 -0.59117691 0.80236373

The Ruby Matrix Eigensystem code produces the following results:

Matrix U (first row)

[0.7408479676229094, -0.1086168097636038, -0.1983599695144702, -0.5690831468812522, -0.27594269683347544]

...

Eigenvector s

[2.3213120745694042, 1.478946829710326, 0.6513267439220222]

Matrix VT

[0.5075238412366166, 0.6681010991839039, 0.544114392242743]

[-0.8577279545170795, 0.4518304852203834, 0.2452589828435646]

[-0.08198967383992087, -0.5911769057522231, 0.8023637326604754]

The difference between negative an positive values is based on the calculation of the Eigenvalues and does not influence the overall result. The absolute values count.

When you look at the result of Matrix U of the Ruby code it starts to differ from the Numpy Code starting with column 4+

The Sigma and the V Matrix are ok.

As test you can run this code as well with the following Matrix

```
A = array([[4,-5,-1],[7,-2,3],[-1,4,-3],[8,2,6]]) #for Python
a = Matrix[[4,-5,-1],[7,-2,3],[-1,4,-3],[8,2,6]] #for Ruby
```

In this case both results are the same. And when you check A = USVT the results produce the original A Matrix again. So the general system appeared to work.

Did anyone has an idea why the results differ?

Any help appreciated

Krid